# Remove APKs for old API levels

Tags: android, google-play

I have some old APKs published in the Google Play Console from over a year ago that target API Levels 9-13. Newer versions of the same app target higher API levels.

I want to remove support for the old app versions, our REST API will no longer support these. We have virtually nobody using these old app versions.

But I cannot find a way to unpublish this old APK from the store. Is there no way to remove old APKs and disable downloads for old API levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct: there is no way to remove old APKs and disable downloads for old API levels on Google Play. Once you support a certain device/API level, users must always be able to download some version of your app.

Of course, you can publish a new version of your app specifically for those older API levels that disables no longer supported functionality with a note that they must upgrade their device to a supported API level to continue to use the app.

Make sure the version code of your deprecation notice app is higher than the existing API 9-13 devices but lower than the 14+ devices (this ensures that the deprecation notice app does not get served to any device running API 14+).